Manage concurrent users per single subscription
I am implementing a functionality in which user can take one subscription &** maximum 10 account can be created per single subscription but only 3 concurrent users are allowed**.
I am using standard approach of session time out from server side.
The problem I am facing is what if 3rd user directly closes the tab/browser or clicks back button, It will not call logout and session will not be terminated. So user4 is not able to connect the application even if 3rd user is not using it.
Suggest me any efficient solution in which that condition leads to call of logout api.

beforeunload event handling
beforeunload event is triggered even if user reloads the website, It should not call logout api. I      am not able to abstract difference between user has clicked reload button or closed the tab !

visibility change
I am calling logout api when visibility changes to hidden, but it calls logout even in minimizing of tab & tab switch too. that I dont want.

Socket approach
As my application is loosely coupled, It leads to too much stress on server, I dont want to moniter live communication with client. my purpose is only that generally user dont click on logout api, he/she directly closes the tab/browser.. I want to handle only that.


I am using jQuery in frontend & C# in backend.

how about a low iteration polling, so the client polls the server to let it know its still connected, and then users will automatically be disconnected within about a minute, and on the login screen you can show a last seen etc when 3 users are already connected?
Obviously websockets sound like the ideal solution here like you mentioned, maybe dig deeper into why its not a viable solution for you and re-evaluate if its worth it?

As my web application is not a streaming platform, maintaining live connections with all users (socket approach) unnecessarily burdens the server. Low iteration polling can be helpful.
